Can I grant android permissions to a C++ only NDK compiled application?
I am to port a linux application to Android. Right now it is being compiled with CMake using the NDK toolchain. I want to use NDK features such as the camera but I am getting permission errors at runtime. The application is made up of shell scripts and C++ binaries, no java code.
Is there any way to grant permissions to C++ binaries that are not part of a java application?
For this project, I tried compiling with AOSP instead of the NDK to avoid permission problems, but I am using CMake and relying on third party projects that also use CMake (such as OpenCV) and porting everything to the Soong build system does not seem easy.
I am thinking to try to run my application from within a java app that starts my app from the command line, but I'm not sure if granting permissions to the java app would allow my app to run this way. I also am considering adding java code to my application but it may require a large rework. It seems like there must be a more straightforward way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

Will your application only be deployed devices running your own customized Android OS or will it be deployed on devices for which you are not in complete control of the operating system?

The OS will be customized.
